# ASP.NET MembershipProvider applicattionName attribute: What it works for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

Its my first time asking here, i hope get help, and meanwhile, help you ppl too =)

My question is very simple:

What is the point of the applicationName attribute in the Membership Provider tables in ASP.NET?

I was thinking of implementing my own membership provider, but taking that attribute out. Is there anything wrong with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This attribute is used when you store membership data for multiple applications in the same database. For instance, if you have 2 applications Foo and Bar, you could have a user "John Doe" in both applications, but since they would have different application names, they wouldn't be considered as the same user

Comment: I see, so if i just want to have 2 applicattions using the same data, i dont need that attribute, because if it was like the same app, right?

Thanks for the answer!